# Angular JS $http with SharePoint Rest Parsing the response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

I am getting a very weird response while hitting sharepoint rest endpoint throught `$http`.

```
    var _get = function($scope) {

            var lName = $scope.wp.lName;
            var filter = $scope.wp.filter;
            var url = $scope.wp.url;    

            var differed = $q.defer();

            var tUrl = <url>

            $http({

            method:'GET',
            url:tUrl,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata" }

            })
            .then(
             function (data) {
               $scope.alert = data.data.value;
               differed.resolve($scope.alert);

               },
             function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 console.log(data);
           });

            return differed.promise;
    }
```

Basically, I have built a angular factory that has all the function required to perform crud operations on sharepoint. I call the `SPGet` method to query a sharepoint list for list items. The call resolves successfully without error but I get a very weird output.

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="<base>" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><id>b8b4ee0c-a5ce-4ef0-92ec-b529ccdc2997</id><title /><updated>2015-06-23T14:26:58Z</updated><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'81419977-601f-46bd-aee5-8e6ebbb34b48')/Items(2)</id><category term="SP.Data.SystemAlertListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'81419977-601f-46bd-aee5-8e6ebbb34b48')/Items(2)" /><title /><updated>2015-06-23T14:26:58Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Title>Test B</d:Title><d:Status>In Progress</d:Status><d:Severity>Med</d:Severity></m:properties></content></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'81419977-601f-46bd-aee5-8e6ebbb34b48')/Items(3)</id><category term="SP.Data.SystemAlertListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'81419977-601f-46bd-aee5-8e6ebbb34b48')/Items(3)" /><title /><updated>2015-06-23T14:26:58Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Title>Test C</d:Title><d:Status>Open</d:Status><d:Severity>Low</d:Severity></m:properties></content></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'81419977-601f-46bd-aee5-8e6ebbb34b48')/Items(4)</id><category term="SP.Data.SystemAlertListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'81419977-601f-46bd-aee5-8e6ebbb34b48')/Items(4)" /><title /><updated>2015-06-23T14:26:58Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Title>Test D</d:Title><d:Status>Closed</d:Status><d:Severity>High</d:Severity></m:properties></content></entry><link rel="next" href="http://intersys-tc3:8000/sites/SA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SystemAlert')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_Severity%3dHigh%26p_ID%3d4&amp;%24orderby=Severity+desc&amp;%24top=3&amp;%24select=Title%2cStatus%2cSeverity&amp;%24filter+Status+eq+%27Open%27+or+Status+eq+%27In+Progress%27=" /></feed>"
```

How do I parse this ? It seems to return the the expected items, but I am not sure how to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the output to json using [xml2json.js](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/source/browse/xml2json.js?r=ebaa2598910f0750ff8593a2b259074f52aa25b9) and then iterate it as usual

Answer (score 0):

`odata=nometadata` is used for SharePoint online.

If you are on prem you still want to use `odata=verbose`.

Comment: I am on SharePoint online. Thanks for the info

Comment: According to the request it seems to be on prem (http://intersys-tc3:8000/sites/SA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SystemAlert')) Tested the request in SharePoint online and I get json back as a result.